# Integrate hive Statement

Tags: hive

In these days,I write some hive Statement,but when I integrate hive Statement,I had some problem,The specific circumstances in this（use hadoop clusters）：

when I  runing：

```
from tmp
  insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/out/jpg'
  select count(1) where logdate=0222 and req_uri regexp '\.(jpg|JPG)'；
```

or

```
from tmp
  insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/out/jpg_hit'                 
  select count(1) where logdate=0222 and req_uri regexp '\.(jpg|JPG)' and hit_status="hit";
```

the result is right
under the "/tmp/out/jpg" or "/tmp/out/jpg_hit" ,there are both only one file,the result on the file(the two result is not equal)

but when I runing ：

```
 from tmp
  insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/out/jpg'
  select count(1) where logdate=0222 and req_uri regexp '\.(jpg|JPG)'
  insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/out/jpg_hit'                 
  select count(1) where logdate=0222 and req_uri regexp '\.(jpg|JPG)' and hit_status="hit";
```

under the "/tmp/out/jpg" or "/tmp/out/jpg_hit" ,there are both many files,when I sum each files number ，I found the two result is equal,and equal the large number ,the result is error.
May I ask you how i solve the problem?

Comment: When you do the sum of the second example, is it equal to cross product of the two individual from statements?